# telling luaotfload where to look for fonts

Tags: fonts, texlive, fontspec, ubuntu, linux

The documentation of luaotfload states that on Linux fontconfig is used to find the font locations. However all fonts I install in <strike>`/usr/share/local/fonts`</strike> **edit**: `/usr/local/share/fonts`(as I don't want to mess up my package management) are not visible to luaotfload, but to all other applications in my system which also use fontconfig. How do I tell luaotfload where to look for fonts?

I’m using TeXLive 2012 included in Ubuntu.

Comment: Btw: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This requires a bit of debugging... Do you have a `/etc/fonts/fonts.conf` that references these fonts? It might be quite important as the code of luaotfload relies on this file. If it doesn't work on your system, it might be because of an update in fontconfig files which makes luaotfload code needing an update... If you want, I would be ready to debug it if you provide me a teamviewer or ssh access...

EDIT: this is indeed in relashionship with the debian bug. Actually it's more a bug in luaotfload than in debian or texlive. I'll fix it in the next version, on CTAN today or tomorrow.

Comment: This is a snippet from fonts.conf

    `cat /etc/fonts/fonts.conf | grep /usr/local/`
            
`<dir>/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts</dir> <dir>/usr/local/share/fonts</dir>`

So it is there in the fontconfig files. Other applications are able to use the fonts in `/usr/local/share/fonts/`

Comment: But it looks like i stumbled across the bug in Debian/Ubuntu mentioned above. So I’m gonna install vanilla TeXLive on my notebook when version 2013 comes out.

Answer (score 12):

The environment variable OSFONTDIR will override fontconfig information. Specifying directories with a double trailing slash means "please recurse into subdirectories". For example:

```
OSFONTDIR=${HOME}/.fonts:/usr/share/fonts//:/usr/share/texmf/fonts//
```

EDIT: There seems to be an issue with Debian (and thus Ubuntu) texlive packaging, which provides a default value of /usr/share/font for OSFONTDIR, meaning that fontconfig support is never invoked.

http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=683943

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Thanks! But will it override all settings or will it just add the paths specified? And why doesn’t luaotfload use the paths in my fontconfig configs?

Comment: @TobiasSchula This adds to the existing paths.

Answer (score 9):

put it into `/usr/local/share/fonts/` or alternatively into your home directory into `.fonts/`.

Run `mkluatexfontdb -v | grep "local/share"`  to see what's going on.

Comment: As I stated above, I already put my fonts in `usr/local/share/fonts` `mkluatexfontdb -v | grep "local/share"` outputs nothing, because luaotfload isn’t looking in the local font directory.

However, it looks like it has something to do with ubuntu’s packaging. On my desktop, where I installed vanilla TeXLive, the fonts in local font dir are getting loaded.

Comment: @TobiasSchula: Your questions says your fonts are in `/usr/share/local`, while they should be in `/usr/local/share`. Please read `man hier`

Comment: @MartinSchröder: I’m sorry, that was a typo. Of course the fonts are in `/usr/local/share/` In fact, that’s also the path kde puts them when I choose to install them globally. I didn’t want to offend anyone.

Comment: @TobiasSchula: No harm done. `:-)`